# Scikit ValueError occurred in sentiment news analysis

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

Sorry for the lack of detail, I am just getting into sentiment analysis right now. I am trying to use a naive bayes classifier on my training set, but I have this error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Text": text})

sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
df['sentiment'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: sia.polarity_scores(x)['compound'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['Text'], df['sentiment'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X_train_vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train_vectorized, y_train)

X_test_vectorized = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_vectorized)
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reuters.py", line 28, in <module>
    clf.fit(X_train_vectorized, y_train)
  File "D:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 617, in fit
    Y = labelbin.fit_transform(y)
  File "D:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py", line 321, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(y).transform(y)
  File "D:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py", line 297, in fit
    self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)
  File "D:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 98, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ 0.6808,  0.    ,  0.7717, -0.4939,  0.2944,  0.    , -0.34  ,
       -0.3182,  0.6369, -0.25  , -0.34  , -0.4767, -0.0258, -0.2263,
       -0.5216,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.2732,  0.    ,
        0.128 ,  0.4019, -0.4019,  0.7717, -0.6124,  0.2023,  0.    ,
        0.4019, -0.3818, -0.4939,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
        0.    ,  0.4019, -0.296 , -0.7003,  0.0772]),)
```

I hope I am not wasting your time. I appreciate the help.